# How to restart sequential pattern, starting from clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 orange buttons, i'm creating a setInterval function that calls another function in order to make the 4 buttons change color every three secondes, that stuff works well.

Now imagine the current button that is gray is the button 1, logically the next one to change will be button 2, if i click on button 3, i want the button 4 to change and not the 2, so i want to change the next button.

Here is my [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pitmit/y0dc5ooc/15/)

here is my code :

```js
var z = 1;
 function updateColor(btn) {
     
     // defilement des boutons de jaune a gris sur desktop
     $('.all-divs').find('.btn').removeClass('btn-current');
     z++;
     $('#btn-'+z).addClass('btn-current').siblings('.btn-current').removeClass('btn-current');
     if(z == 4){z = 0;}
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(updateColor, 3000);
    });

    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $('.btn').removeClass("btn-current");
        $(this).addClass("btn-current");
    });
```

```css
.btn{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:10px auto;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:orange;
  border-radius:50px;
}

.btn-current{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:10px auto;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-divs">


  <div class="btn" id="btn-1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn-2">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn-3">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn-4">
    4
  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you all

Comment: You stated what you want to achieve, but did not mention where you have the problem or what your question is.

Comment: My question is : how to make to change the color of the button next to the one i clicked, and make the change follow the new order and not the "automatic one"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your button click event, just make this change:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.btn').removeClass("btn-current");
    $(this).addClass("btn-current");
    z = this.id.split('-')[1];
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/y0dc5ooc/30/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If I understood correctly, it should help. https://jsfiddle.net/y0dc5ooc/26/

```
  <div class="btn" id="btn-1">1</div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn-2">2</div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn-3">3</div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn-4">4</div>

function updateColor(id) {
    $('.btn').removeClass('btn-current');
    var btnId = '#btn-' + id;
    $(btnId).addClass('btn-current');
 }


 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.btn').click(function(e){
         var id = this.getAttribute('id').substr(4);
         if(id ==4)
         {id = 1;}
         else{ id = parseInt(id) + 1;}
         updateColor(id);
     });
   });
```

Comment: hi @arturas maybe i didn't make it easy to understand (because of my bad english), but thank you for your help. what i wanted was to keep the automatic changing, and if i click on one button, the next one changes and we lose the automatic changing